# Shipping is not showing in checkout magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout

Installed the Magento2 in my host.Added some Products for testing purpose.In front end checkout page shipping information is not showing.can u plz give me suggestions for solve this issue...?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRGCv.png]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your product is properly a virtual or downloadable product in the type, these don't require shipping so Magento skips the step.

Check in the backend

Comment: How can we implement this for virtual products. I am using virtual products for color swatching options.

Comment: @akhil, to use shipping methods you need to add to cart simple, bundle or configured products.

Comment: 2 days and got the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of issue on Magento `2.4.5`.

For me:

- Both the "Shipping" and "Payments" tabs were shown on the checkout page.
- But, the "Shipping Address" and "Shipping Method" sections were empty.

**Solution**

The fix for me was to go through the custom HTML templates and make sure there were no self-closing tags (i.e., `<div/>`, `<span/>`, `<each/>`, `<render/>`, etc).

**Explanation of a possible reason for the issue:**

> HTML5 basically behaves as if the trailing slash is not there. There
> is no such thing as a self-closing tag in HTML5 syntax.
>
> - Self-closing tags on *non-void* elements like `<p/>`, `<div/>` will not work
>   at all. The trailing slash will be ignored, and these will be treated
>   as opening tags. This is likely to lead to nesting problems.
>
>   This is true regardless of whether there is whitespace in front of the
>   slash: `<p />` and `<div />` also won't work for the same reason.
> - Self-closing tags on *void* elements like `<br/>` or `<img src="" alt=""/>`
>   will work, but only because the trailing slash is ignored, and in this
>   case that happens to result in the correct behaviour.
>
> The result is, anything that worked in your old "XHTML 1.0 served as
> text/html" will continue to work as it did before: trailing slashes on
> non-void tags were not accepted there either whereas the trailing
> slash on void elements worked.
>
> Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38068359/327862

Answer (score -1):

Please manually delete the `var` and `pub` sub-folders then run following commands:

```
setup:upgrade
setup:di:compile
setup:static-content:deploy
```

Thanks.